# Please help me find this Harry/Draco veela fic?

Tags: story-identification, harry-potter, fan-fiction, drarry

A while ago I read this Drarry Veela fic that I cannot find now. I remember some parts of it, though.

I think it started with Harry in Dumbledore's office. Draco, his parents and I think Snape were there.

Harry and Draco had special quarters and I remember that later on Draco's parents visited and there was this part where Draco made a menu for their dinner with the Malfoys.

Narcissa, Lucius, Snape, Ron and Hermione all turned out to be supportive.

I remember that Snape was a bit bitter in the middle of the fanfic while he and Harry were talking because he had lent him a book on Oclumency and never got it back. But Harry then said he hadn't received it. Snape even vomited because he realized that he had been essentially violating Harry's mind. A few chapters later he found Mundungus Fletcher (Snape had given him the book and told him to give it to Harry but he sold it instead) and demanded that he find the original book.

I don't remember how but Draco went missing (during a Quiditch game maybe...) and it turned out a girl (Pansy maybe) was trying to r*pe him to become pregnant with his baby. I think she wanted his Veela instincts to somehow transfer to the child so that he would marry her. Dobby was the one who found them and she was expelled I think. Also, she had force-fed him potions to make sure she got pregnant and she was 100% sure she was but for some reason it didn't work.

When they bonded (I don't remember how) I think the entire school felt it. There was this paragraph describing Ron and Hermione's reaction - they were resigned to it but happy nonetheless.

I don't remember anything else, but if you could please find it you'd be doing me a huge favour!

Comment: Take a look at this [guide](http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/a/9337/68872) to help jog your memory and [edit] any more details. Also, take a look at our [tour] to get a better understanding of our site and earn your first [badge](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/badges)!

Comment: After reading through some of these "What fanfics are these?" questions, I'm unable to ever watch Harry Potter the same way again.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

## I think it's probably [*DragonKin* by Fyreheart.](https://m.fanfiction.net/s/5475405/)

The story seems to centre on Harry becoming a dragon and being tutored by some kind of dragon spirit guardian. It has the following elements.

- It begins in Albus Dumbledore's study.

  > No one in the room remembered seeing Albus Dumbledore this visibly upset in recent memory.
- There's a meeting there between Harry, Dumbledore and the Malfoys.

  > There were four chairs in front of the Headmaster's desk, but it was the occupants of three of those chairs that made Harry pause. Draco Malfoy and his parents, Lucius and Narcissa turned to look at him as he entered.
- Draco is a Veela.

  > The Malfoys had to be part Veela and one of them had chosen him as a Mate. He considered the expressions he had seen on their faces. Lucius and Narcissa had appeared respectful and determined. Draco had looked sincere, hopeful, but also fearful as if afraid of rejection. So Draco had come into his Veela inheritance and identified him as his Mate? Mate with Draco? Not bloody likely!
- Harry and Draco have shared quarters.

  > "If you choose to accept the bond, I can offer you and Mr. Malfoy new quarters. You would each have your own bedroom, but would have a shared common room, similar to what the Head Boy and Girl share."
- Draco prepares a menu for their dinner with his parents.

  > He noticed a parchment on the table in Draco's handwriting and realized it was his proposed menu. It began with stuffed artichokes topped with an asiago sauce for an appetizer, portabella mushroom soup, followed by grilled salmon fillets with roasted redskin potatoes and fresh vegetables. Draco apparently recommended a Vosne Romanée wine to accompany the main course. He had a couple of different desserts written down including champagne and strawberry mousse, treacle tart with clotted cream, and a warm cinnamon and vanilla bread pudding.
- Snape lends Mundungus Fletcher a book about Occlumency.

  > "I'm looking for a particular object; a book in fact. I heard that you can sometimes find things that others cannot" the man murmured from the shadows.
  > Dung frowned slightly. "A book? Nowt much call fer books. Wha' kind is it?"
  > "A somewhat rare book called 'Mind Magic: The Art of Occlumency'. I had a copy once, but it disappeared."
- Snape meant for Fletcher to give the book to Harry but he sells it.

  > The ginger-haired man preened a little. "How much do ye want ta pay fer the book if I find it fer ya?"
  > "I don't know, Fletcher. For how much did you sell it?" The figure leaned forward into the light and pushed back the hood revealing the cold features of Severus Snape. The smaller man tried to stand up, but found himself frozen in his chair.
  > "I gave you a book to give to Harry Potter, Fletcher. I stressed the importance of giving it to him immediately. I find that you never did so. That means you lied to me when you agreed to pass it on to Potter. It means you stole a valuable book from me."

Comment: Is it any good?

Comment: @Valorum I was really only skimming it but the first scene I came across had Draco stroking Harry's dragon  scales so I'm going to go with 'not my cup of tea'.

Comment: Thank you The Dark Lord for answering!!!! I can't believe it, I was honestly thinking of reading DragonKin again after finding it in a community in fanfiction.net, I didn't know it was the fanfic I was searching for! You're a lifesaver!!!

Comment: @SolisC. You're welcome.